# How to access sub property in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble with some simple functionality of Pandas. I read a df from a json file and when I do

```
df.iloc[0]['someprop']['someotherprop']
```

it all works. When I do

```
df.iloc[0:1]['someprop']['someotherprop']
```

I expect it to work same as before but instead I get `KeyError: 'someotherprop'`

Interestingly `df.iloc[0:1]['someprop']` works for some reason. This is quite confusing.

Can someone please tell me, how do I access the second property? I want to do:

```
df['someprop']['someotherprop'].unique()
```

at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `df.iloc[0]` returns a `Series`, where `df.iloc[0:1]` returns a `DataFrame`:

```
type(df.iloc[0])
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
type(df.iloc[0:1])
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Both can then be indexed by `someprop`, with the first returning a value (presumably a dict in your case), while the second returns a `Series`. So to access the `someotherprop` value in the second case, you need to *first* index into the series i.e.:

```
df.iloc[0:1]['someprop'][0]['someotherprop']
```

To get all the unique values, you'd need to iterate them for example:

```
unq = set(d['someotherprop'] for d in df.iloc[0:1]['someprop'])
```

Or for the whole dataframe:

```
unq = set(d['someotherprop'] for d in df['someprop'])
```

You could also access the entire series using `json_normalize`:

```
sop = pd.json_normalize(df['someprop'])['someotherprop']
```

Comment: so how do you find the unique `someotherprop`?

Comment: You need to iterate the values; see my edit

Comment: When I do `df['someprop'].to_frame()['someotherprop'] ` it should work But I still get `keyError`. I don't get it

Comment: If `someprop` is a dict, you could use `pd.json_normalize(df['someprop'])['someotherprop']`

Comment: that was the answer: pd.json_normalize(df['someprop'])['someotherprop']

Comment: @JeniaIvanov good to hear. I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

So Nick above gave me a nice hint.

Basically the answer as far as I can tell right now is:

```
inner = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(df['prop'].to_json())).T
```

Looks hedious but let me explain it line by line.

First I noticed that when I do `df['prop'].to_frame().keys()` I get one key and it's `prop` rather than what I expected which is a bunch of keys corresponding to the object inside `prop`.

So from here I turned the `df['prop']` to json `df['prop'].to_json()` and read it back as a dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(df['prop'].to_json()))
```

Then I had to transpose it because the keys were on the i axis and the values on the j so the dataframe was like 11X100K.

This is very clumbsy but perhaps someone can give a better way how to with with json and dataframe?

P.S. just to re-iterate, `df['prop']` is a whole object `{"X" : 123, "Y": "abc...}`